# Excel SUMPRODUCT - how to deal with a #VALUE! error if array contains a text

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, array-formulas, sumproduct

I'm using SUMPRODUCT function formula (here simplified version):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A3:A11="aaa"),B3:B11,C3:C11*0.8)
```

where I want to multiply the values in column3 by a number (for example 0.8) but once there is a text value in the column I get a #VALUE! error. I've tried wrapping the array of column3 in an IFERROR and other similar functions but nothing seems to work... Any idea how I can deal with this issue?

(Note: replacing text with 0 in the table is not a solution for me as I want to keep the text there)

[image: Excel_pic]

Comment: change `C3:C11*0.8` to `Isnumber(C3:C11)*0.8` will work

Comment: Well, this doesn't work because the ISNUMBER function returns True or False (1 or 0). When multiplying with 0,8 it gives me an array of 0,8 instead of 80.

Comment: Hi @MrZH6, because I tested with 1 but not 100, exactly I was seriously confused. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to switch to an array version and add IFERROR:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A3:A11="aaa"),B3:B11,IFERROR(C3:C11*0.8,0))
```

Then depending on one's version one may need to confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the combination of Control+Shift+Enter and IFERROR function gives the desired result. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm just thinking now: I will do a lot of copying of this formula. Do I have to be aware of something? I'm a little bit cautios when using these CSE formulas...

Comment: If you copy the cell or drag it, then you only need to do the CSE on the first cell.  If you place the formula in the formula bar or edit the formula then you will need to use the CSE